# Cascade persist creates duplicate rows?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I'm creating a database entity object `Order`, and assign it to multiple entities of type `BookingCode`.

Problem: this creates a single order in db, which is fine. But the order itself has a `@OneToOne` `OrderDescription`, which occurs duplicate in the database.

```
@Entity
public class BookingCode {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH})
    private Order order;
}

@Entity
public class Order {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String orderName;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private OrderDescription description;
}

@Entity
public class OrderDescription {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    //for simplicity just one text element; of course multiple fields in real life
    private String text;

    @OneToOne
    private Order order;
}
```

Test:

```
Order order = new Order();
order.setOrderName("test");

OrderDescription d = new OrderDescription("testdescr");
d.setOrder(order);
order.setDescription(d);

List<BookingCodes> codes = new ArrayList<>();

BookingCode code = new BookingCode();
code.setOrder(order);
codes.add(order);

BookingCode code2 = new BookingCode();
code2.setOrder(order); //using the same offer entity!
codes.add(order2);

codes = dao.save(codes); //CrudRepository from Spring

dao.findOne(codes.get(0).getId()); //this works, find an order which has one of the OrderDescriptions
```

Result:
In my database I then have **two** `OrderDescription` entries, where I would expect only one, because I reused the same `Order` object and assigned it to different `BookingCode` objects.

Like:

```
table order_descrption:
1;"de";"testdescr";"123456"
2;"de";"testdescr";"123456"
```

As `Order` has a `@OneToOne` relation to `OrderDescription`
And I even don't understand why the `select` using `findOne()` works correctly. Because in database I now have two `OrderDescriptions` that map to the same `Order`, but an `Order` can only have one of them.

Comment: Do you have a proper hashCode and equals method?

Comment: I don't have any hash or equals methods. But shouldn't hibernate be able to detect that I'm about to save the same `Order` and within the same `OrderDescription`?

Comment: Not without proper equals/hashcode implementations. JPA is quite picky on how it works. It replaces objects with managed objects at which point they don't match anymore. Without proper equals/hashcode implementations hibernate cannot detect that.Hence the suggestion to first persist the order, before anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Persist the order first and then assign it to both bookingCode .

Comment: That works, thanks. Anyways I wonder if it's still possible to save those objects in one go.

Comment: There should be a primary key assigned to order , in order to identify if the orders are same or not

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I had an Order obj and its variable prevOrder was referring to itself i.e. Order entity. And when I stored order, it would end up storing duplicate records for prevOrder.

I had the following code:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "order_id_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "order_id_generator", sequenceName = "order_id_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Long id;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "previous_order_id", unique = true, updatable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
private Order previousOrder;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "previousOrder")
private Order nextOrder;
...
```

I tried various things including overriding equals and hashcode of Order, and adding a OneToOne mappedBy field 'nextOrder' etc. But noticed JPA didn't even call equals() to determine object's uniqueness. Ultimately I found out that JPA uses **id field as the object's identifier** and I wasn't storing the generated id while storing the object to a distrobuted cache. So it was all the time creating fresh objects during persistence.